# Node JS and Sequelize Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I got this error when I try to do a query to get an username from an id into a controller. I've tried to fix this problem, but no solution worked, is there any way to get the username through a query?

**User Model:**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
const config = require('../config');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class tb_user extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
    }
  };
  tb_user.init({
    id_user:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey:true,
      autoIncrement:true
    },
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'tb_user',
    freezeTableName:true
  });

  tb_user.associate = models =>{
    tb_user.hasMany(models.tb_tech,{
      foreignKey:'id_user',
      as:'tb_tech',
      onDelete:'CASCADE'
    })
  }
  return tb_user;
};
```

**Supervisor Model:**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class tb_supervisor extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
    }
  };
  tb_supervisor.init({
    id_supervisor:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey:true,
      autoIncrement:true
    },
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'tb_supervisor',
    freezeTableName:true
  });

  tb_supervisor.associate = models =>{
    tb_supervisor.hasMany(models.tb_tech,{
      foreignKey:'id_supervisor',
      as:'tb_tech',
      onDelete:'CASCADE'
    })
  }
  return tb_supervisor;
};
```

**Technician Model:**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class tb_tech extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    }
  };
  tb_tech.init({
    id_tech:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey:true,
      autoIncrement:true
    },
    id_user: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    id_supervisor: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    zone:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    region:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    full_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    tech_type: DataTypes.STRING,
    goal: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    observations: DataTypes.STRING,
    client: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'tb_tech',
    freezeTableName:true
  });

  tb_tech.associate = models =>{
    tb_tech.belongsTo(models.tb_user,{
      foreignKey:'id_user',
      as:'tb_user',
      onDelete:'CASCADE'
    })

    tb_tech.belongsTo(models.tb_supervisor,{
      foreignKey:'id_supervisor',
      as:'tb_supervisor',
      onDelete:'CASCADE'
    })
  }

  return tb_tech;
};
```

**Supervisor Controller:**

```
const Supervisor = require("../models").tb_supervisor;
const Tecnico = require("../models").tb_tech;
const Usuario = require("../models").tb_user;

module.exports = {
   getAllSupervisors(req,res){
        const id_supervisor = req.params.id_supervisor;
        return Supervisor
                .findAll({
                    include:[{
                        model:Tecnico, as:'tb_tech',
                        where:{
                            id_supervisor:id_supervisor
                        }
                    }]
                })
                .then(sup => {
                    const resObj = sup.map(supervisor => {
                        return Object.assign(
                            {},
                            {
                                id_supervisor : supervisor.id_supervisor,
                                username: supervisor.username,
                                email: supervisor.email,
                                technician: supervisor.tb_tech.map(tec => {
                                    return Object.assign(
                                        {},
                                        {
                                            tech_id : tec.id_tech,
                                            id_user: Usuario.findOne({
                                                where:{
                                                    id_user:tec.id_user
                                                },
                                                attributes:['username']
                                            }).then(user => res.json(user)).catch(error => console.log(error)),
                                            id_supervisor: tec.id_supervisor,
                                            zone: tec.zone,
                                            region: tec.region,
                                            full_name: tec.full_name,
                                            tech_type:tec.tech_type,
                                            goal: tec.goal,
                                            observations: tec.observations,
                                            client: tec.client
                                        }
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        )
                    })
                    res.status(200).json(resObj);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    res.status(500).send({message:error.message});
                })
    },
}
```

**Routes:**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const UsuarioController = require("../controllers/user");
const TecnicoController = require("../controllers/tech");
const SupervisorController = require("../controllers/supervisor");

router.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
    );
    next();
});

router.get('/users/getAllUsers/:id_user',UsuarioController.getAllUsers);

router.get('/supervisor/getAllSupervisors/:id_supervisor',SupervisorController.getAllSupervisors);

router.get('/techs/getAllTechs',TecnicoController.getAllTechs);

module.exports = router;
```

In postman, the query is fine, but the field where I require the username is a blank object and the console throws the following error. Can a query be made within another query?.

**Images:**
[image]
[image]

The question is, what is the source of the error? Can you make a query within another query ?.

**Beforehand thank you very much.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggest this is happening because you are trying to send response headers more then once i.e at first and second place which is not possible, try to change your code according to asynchronous behaviour of nodejs use async await to avoid function chaining avoid making async calls in map, filter and other async functions of array as they are not waited foruse native or for of loop instead

```
module.exports = {
  getAllSupervisors(req, res) {
    const id_supervisor = req.params.id_supervisor;
    return Supervisor.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Tecnico,
          as: "tb_tech",
          where: {
            id_supervisor: id_supervisor
          }
        }
      ]
    })
      .then((sup) => {
        const resObj = sup.map((supervisor) => {
          return Object.assign(
            {},
            {
              id_supervisor: supervisor.id_supervisor,
              username: supervisor.username,
              email: supervisor.email,
              technician: supervisor.tb_tech.map((tec) => {
                return Object.assign(
                  {},
                  {
                    tech_id: tec.id_tech,
                    id_user: Usuario.findOne({
                      where: {
                        id_user: tec.id_user
                      },
                      attributes: ["username"]
                    })
                      .then((user) => res.json(user)) // sending response here for first time
                      .catch((error) => console.log(error)),
                    id_supervisor: tec.id_supervisor,
                    zone: tec.zone,
                    region: tec.region,
                    full_name: tec.full_name,
                    tech_type: tec.tech_type,
                    goal: tec.goal,
                    observations: tec.observations,
                    client: tec.client
                  }
                );
              })
            }
          );
        });
        res.status(200).json(resObj); //for second time
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
      });
  }
};
```

To avoid this try doing something like this

```
module.exports = {
  async getAllSupervisors(req, res) {
    const id_supervisor = req.params.id_supervisor;
    const sub = await Supervisor.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Tecnico,
          as: "tb_tech",
          where: {
            id_supervisor: id_supervisor
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    // const resObj = sup.map((supervisor) => {
    const resObj = [];
    for (const supervisor of sub) {
      resObj.push(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            id_supervisor: supervisor.id_supervisor,
            username: supervisor.username,
            email: supervisor.email,
            technician: supervisor.tb_tech.map((tec) => {
              return Object.assign(
                {},
                {
                  tech_id: tec.id_tech,
                  id_user: await Usuario.findOne({
                    where: {
                      id_user: tec.id_user
                    },
                    attributes: ["username"]
                  }),
                  id_supervisor: tec.id_supervisor,
                  zone: tec.zone,
                  region: tec.region,
                  full_name: tec.full_name,
                  tech_type: tec.tech_type,
                  goal: tec.goal,
                  observations: tec.observations,
                  client: tec.client
                }
              );
            })
          }
        )
      );
    }
    // });
    res.status(200).json(resObj); //second
    res.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your supervisor controller.

```
.then(sup => {
    const resObj = sup.map(supervisor => { // POINT ---- 1
        return Object.assign(
            {},
            {
                id_supervisor : supervisor.id_supervisor,
                username: supervisor.username,
                email: supervisor.email,
                technician: supervisor.tb_tech.map(tec => {
                    return Object.assign(
                        {},
                        {
                            tech_id : tec.id_tech,
                            id_user: Usuario.findOne({ // POINT --------- 2
                                where:{
                                    id_user:tec.id_user
                                },
                                attributes:['username']
                            }).then(user => res.json(user) // POINT 4).catch(error => console.log(error)),
                            id_supervisor: tec.id_supervisor,
                            zone: tec.zone,
                            region: tec.region,
                            full_name: tec.full_name,
                            tech_type:tec.tech_type,
                            goal: tec.goal,
                            observations: tec.observations,
                            client: tec.client
                        }
                    )
                })
            }
        )
    })
    res.status(200).json(resObj);  // POINT  ------ 3
})
```

POINT 2: Your `Usuario.findOne` is DB query and it is async means it will take time.
Because of this your  POINT 1 `sup.map(supervisor => {` will go to in async execution and nodejs will continue to work on next line.

So POINT 3 will be executed in the next event loop. Thus at the time of executing POINT 3 your `resObj` is null and express returned response to the request.
But while executing POINT 4 you have return statement ( that is another return statement) No 2 return cant happen in 1 request.

Check async nature of nodejs and use promises correctly.